# Plot with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a sample data :

```
dput(Meanws)
structure(list(m = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
    TimeStamp = structure(c(1390065206.10932, 1392422100, 1394970900, 
    1397606100, 1400241300, 1402876500, 1405511700, 1404511324.74897, 
    1389786772.51605, 1381924500, 1384559700, 1387139253.87506
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), MeanWindSpeed102.5 = c(6.12204448017149, 
    6.54359101516919, 7.32096804511278, 6.29412731481481, 5.57985663082437, 
    5.45419907407407, 5.56513216845878, 5.89754085449892, 5.25164781412412, 
    7.2097311827957, 7.13449768518519, 8.17678562698607), MeanWindSpeed100.0 = c(6.05450964630225, 
    6.44605892648775, 7.23954417293233, 6.22275, 5.48870967741935, 
    5.3645625, 5.5027396953405, 5.8113152195314, 5.15942678080098, 
    7.10622311827957, 7.03509259259259, 8.07463211928624), MeanWindSpeed76.6 = c(5.40157020364416, 
    5.81589848308051, 6.54625, 5.69984953703704, 5.03385752688172, 
    4.88327777777778, 4.99367831541219, 5.27035833825556, 4.66075512075818, 
    6.43867159498208, 6.37995138888889, 7.36318259594231), MeanWindSpeed53.8 = c(4.59780010718114, 
    5.15528588098016, 5.77638862781955, 5.02735648148148, 4.51373431899642, 
    4.34299537037037, 4.38113127240143, 4.5946288639496, 3.98211861815958, 
    5.64894041218638, 5.64181712962963, 6.57381080420435)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("m", "TimeStamp", "MeanWindSpeed102.5", 
"MeanWindSpeed100.0", "MeanWindSpeed76.6", "MeanWindSpeed53.8"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

It is monthly wind speed in different height.

```
 head(Meanws)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
      m           TimeStamp MeanWindSpeed102.5 MeanWindSpeed100.0 MeanWindSpeed76.6 MeanWindSpeed53.8
  <dbl>              <dttm>              <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
1     1 2014-01-18 17:13:26           6.122044           6.054510          5.401570          4.597800
2     2 2014-02-14 23:55:00           6.543591           6.446059          5.815898          5.155286
3     3 2014-03-16 11:55:00           7.320968           7.239544          6.546250          5.776389
4     4 2014-04-15 23:55:00           6.294127           6.222750          5.699850          5.027356
5     5 2014-05-16 11:55:00           5.579857           5.488710          5.033858          4.513734
6     6 2014-06-15 23:55:00           5.454199           5.364562          4.883278          4.342995
```

The point is every time that I load the data I have different height and I have to manually adjust the plot command. even I tried to reshape the data like :

```
c=Meanws %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = "key", value = "value", -TimeStamp,-m) %>%
  tidyr::extract(col = key, into = c("variable", "height"), regex = "([:alpha:]+)([:digit:]+)") %>%
  tidyr::spread(key = variable, value = value)
```

And the new data frame is now like :

```
head(c)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
      m           TimeStamp height MeanWindSpeed
  <dbl>              <dttm>  <chr>         <dbl>
1     1 2014-01-18 17:13:26    100      6.054510
2     1 2014-01-18 17:13:26    102      6.122044
3     1 2014-01-18 17:13:26     53      4.597800
4     1 2014-01-18 17:13:26     76      5.401570
5     2 2014-02-14 23:55:00    100      6.446059
6     2 2014-02-14 23:55:00    102      6.543591
```

It looks better now ! but I don't know how to do grouping now and how to use ggplot to get one single plot for all monthly average data.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. I assume that you want the x-axis to be the month (`m`) and the y-axis to be `MeanWindSpeed`. Do you want a cure for each value of `height`? Or do you want to take the average over all heights and just plot one single curve?

Comment: @Stibu I want to have m on x-axis and MeanWindSpeed in y. by c I could get rid of different hight. if I add `dplyr::group_by(height,m) %>% dplyr::summarise(w=mean(MeanWindSpeed))` But How to plot it now ?

Comment: What I still need to know whether you want to have one curve for each value of height or just one single curve that represents to average wind speed over all heights?

Comment: @Stibu one curve for each height

Answer (score 3):

You have already prepared your data appropriately such that it can be plotted with `ggplot`.  What you need to do is map `m` on the x-axis, `MeanWindSpeed` on the y-axis and `height` on the color:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(c, aes(x = m, y = MeanWindSpeed, colour = height)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12) +
    labs(x = "Month", y ="Mean Wind Speed", colour = "Height")
```

[image]

If you want points instead of lines, just replace `geom_line()` by `geom_point()`. Or you can also use them both to have points and lines.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know this ggplot at all :(

Comment: In my oppinion, `ggplot` is an excellent package for plotting in R. But it takes a little effort to learn how to use it. There are plenty of resources on the web that will help you. For example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/basic-introduction-to-ggplot2/ and http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html. Here you find lots of examples: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/